# Specify variable length in VBA Format function

Tags: vba

I know there are other ways to do this, I am just wondering whether there is a built-in (or at least elegant) method.

For example, `Format(123, "00000")` results in the string `00123`.
How would you make the number of leading zeros variable?
The [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/gg251755.aspx) doesn't seem to give any simple method to do this.

In C, it can be done as follows

```
char * output; // allocated somewhere
int width = 5;
int number = 123;

sprintf(output, "%0*d", width, number);
```

(`output` in this case is `00123`, and changing `width` will change the number of leading zeros)

Comment: maybe this can help you: ["printf()-like Format Function in VBScript"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/250/printf-like-Format-Function-in-VBScript). You may need to enable the reference to VBScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `string()` function to replicate the number of `0`s

```
Sub formatTest()

    req_format = String(5, "0")
    result = Format(123, req_format)

End Sub
```

And in one line of code `result = Format(123, String(5, "0"))`

Comment: I was hoping there was some fine print that I missed about Format itself. Your method works great. I particularly like the single line method that avoids clutter. Thanks!